# Extra empty string when parsing string into arguments

Tags: c, parsing, exec

I'm trying to use the following parsing function I found online:

```
void parse(char *line, char **argv)
{
    while (*line != '\0') {     /* if not the end of line */ 
        while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n') {
            *line++ = '\0';     /* replace white spaces with 0    */
        }
        *argv++ = line;         /* save the argument position     */
        while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' &&  *line != '\t' && *line != '\n') {
            line++;             /* skip the argument until ...    */
        }
    }
    *argv = '\0';               /* mark the end of argument list  */
}
```

And this works really nicely for what I want to do (making my own `char **argv`), but it has one drawback. It creates an extra empty string in my `argv` after my last argument and before my NULL. Can any of you see where I can change the code to fix this? I've tried stepping through with gdb but I can't figure it out.

Example: If my line is simply `"1"`, `*argv =[1, , (null)]`. I need to get rid of that empty string.

I've tried directly changing the blank space, but that's not working. For example I've tried:

```
char **temp = args;
int count =0;
while (*temp != NULL) {
    *temp = *(temp +1);
    count++;
}
args[count] = NULL;
```

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your issue.

Comment: Interesting. I can't imagine my other code is messing it up. All I've done is read a single line of a file into a buffer. Thanks for trying!

Comment: It seem that Blank  not exist.

Comment: [Check DEMO](http://ideone.com/oXa0xp) `[1, NULL]`

Comment: I don't know how my code was changing it so much that I was getting an empty string that you can't replicate. All I was doing was reading in a line, and the solution below solved my problem.

Comment: _If my line is simply "1"_ : `"1"` --> `"1\n"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you present will include an empty string (which is not well characterized as "an empty *space*") at the end of the argument list if the string pointed to by `line` ends in whitespace.  You can avoid that by first truncating any trailing whitespace (spaces, tabs, and/or newlines), by reading `line` in a way that avoids any possibility of such trailing whitespace being included, or by *forcing* whitespace always and changing the penultimate line to `*--argv = '\0'`.

While I'm at it I observe that although `'\0'` is in fact a perfectly *valid* expression of a null pointer, it is nevertheless much less clear than the macro `NULL`, or even, in this case, plain `0`.

Comment: Good point. I'll change my wording. And I think I tried that solution to no success, but I'll try again and make sure.

Comment: I stand corrected. I tried that on the argv further up the function. The extra empty string is gone. Many thanks!